# How to set variable to external content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code that uses JQuery to output a live calculation from data entered in a text field. It all works fine as seen below:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#w_amount', function(){
   // alert('pressed')
    var totalcost= 11 * $(this).val() 
    $(".total_cost").html(totalcost);
})
```

and it's outputted here:

```
 <span class=\"total_cost\" style=\"display: inline; vertical-align: inherit;\">0</span>
```

Currently the code takes whatever number is entered into the text field and multiplies it by 11. However what I want it to do is multiply it by the number located at the following url: https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?coin=DOGE

There is just a number at that url nothing else i.e. 0.00014253

I'd appreciate any help you can give! Received a great response last time.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? Your statement is that it works!

Comment: He wants to use the number located at an external link instead of 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of [Cross-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy),  you can't make an ajax request to it. Instead I would recommend using curl or something on your server and then either input that value into the page at load time, or make an ajax request to your server which would then make the request to that link.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as suggested by @Sukima: the `data` parameter renamed to `url_figure` to avoid declaring unnecessary variable.

Assuming that your jQuery script, HTML files are both hosted on the same server that has the figure (eobot.com) then here is how it could be done.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#w_amount', function(){
   // alert('pressed')
    $.get( "https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?coin=DOGE", function( url_figure) {
         var totalcost= url_figure * $(this).val() 
         $(".total_cost").html(totalcost);

    });

});
```

Comment: CORS will stop this. Does eobot.com provide a CORS header?

Comment: I'd use `text()` as a mater of practice in this case.

Comment: Why not label the `data` variable as `url_figure` and avoid the extra `var url_figure = data;` line all together?

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks for the response. Unfortunately they are on different servers so am going to try and research/implement the methods suggested by winhowes.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Well, I don't like to leave you at an *"it's not possible"* answer so here you go:</sup>

Name your file **test.php** and use it on a live server or on *localhost*

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET["getCoinValue"]) ){
    $val = @file_get_contents("https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?coin=DOGE");
    exit ($val ? "$val" : "Could not retrieve data");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>GET DOGE</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    W <input id="w_amount" type="text"><br>
    * <input class="doge_value" type="text" readonly><br>
    = <input class="total_cost" type="text" readonly>
</body>
<script>
$(function(){
    var $dogeValue = $(".doge_value");
    var $totalCost = $(".total_cost");
    $("#w_amount").on('keyup', function(){
        var thisValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        $.ajax({
            data    : {"getCoinValue":true} ,
            success : function( resp ){
                $dogeValue.val( resp );
                $totalCost.val( thisValue * resp );
            }, 
            error : function(x, e){ console.log(x, e);  }
        });

    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

The trick is to fool AJAX that the result is on our server,
achieved by pulling the content from the external site using PHP and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> On "input" AJAX contacts the same .php file using GET (jQ's AJAX defauly `type`).
>   PHP gets the content from the **external URI to our server**, and exits with a String response.
>   AJAX serves the response back from our server (without COP issues)
>   The result is than multiplied by the entered value.